# Time series from Dataframe: Plotting X-values from rows and Y-values from Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, time-series

I'm trying to create a line plot (time series) from a filtered data frame that is 17 rows x 33 columns.

To provide some background, I am tracking gene expression over certain time points.
Every row in this data frame corresponds to a particular exon. Every column on this data frame corresponds to a time-point, while the VALUES INSIDE the columns correspond to level of gene expression.

This is what my data frame looks like:
[image: Image depicting the data frame I'm working with]

I want to create a line graph where every line corresponds to a row on this data frame (exon), while the y-values correspond to level of gene expression (values inside each column).

I'm trying to get a resulting graph that would something like this:

[image]

Is there anyway to do this? I've tried to set the x and y axes individually but I think the error might stem from using labels and integer-values interchangeably.
This is the method I tried using:

```
df2.plot(x=df2['0'], y=df2['38', '56', '65', '79', '99', '110', '128', '138', 
                       '146', '171', '183', '198', '206', '218', '231', '238', 
                       '258', '276', '283', '303', '316', '331', '343', '367', 
                       '379', '383', '412', '430', '438', '471', '484', '496', '521'])
```

But this produces this instead:

[image: An image of the failed line plot attempt]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I got the problem correctly, transpose should help here:

[image]

[image]

P.S. It was randomly generated data

**UPDATE:**

Will reflect comment here for the sake of consistency. Seems like the column name is a string in your case, here is how it should work in that case

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that definitely looks like what I'm trying to achieve! Unfortunately  I tried using this method but got "KeyError: None of [0] are in the columns." I think the issue may be that the first column is named "0" ?  Not sure how I would change that though.

Comment: Good. In my case the column name was integer. Looks like this option should work for you:

df.set_index("0")

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've discovered that the first column is actually an index, which is why it's so finicky with the code. I have changed the name of the index by using df2.index.name = 'exon' and then ran your code. It works thanks!